# How can I get the maximum range that exists in an arbitrary list of integers?

Tags: prolog

I'm new to prolog, I don't understand much of the language and I had already posted a question about Prolog before. Now I want to obtain, from a list of integers, the numbers in the interval that contains the largest amount of numbers in that list, in other words the maximum range. Example:

```
maxrange(X,Y,[1,3,2,7,4,5,6,9,8]).
X = 1, Y= 10. 
maxrange(1,10,[1,3,2,7,4,5,6,9,8].
True.
maxrange(1,8,[1,3,2,7,4,5,6,9,8].
False.
```

Lists must contain all numbers between [X,Y) and must be the maximum interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
maxrange(A, B, List) :-
    maxranges(List, Ranges),
    member(A-B, Ranges).

maxranges(List, Ranges) :-
    sort(List, [Min|Sorted]),
    maxranges_loop(Sorted, Min, Min, [], Ranges).

maxranges_loop([], A, B, Ranges, UpdatedRanges) :-
    update(Ranges, A, B, UpdatedRanges).
maxranges_loop([X|Xs], A, B, Ranges, UpdatedRanges) :-
    Bool is abs(sign(X - (B + 1))),
    maxranges_case(Bool, X, Xs, A, B, Ranges, UpdatedRanges).

maxranges_case(0, X, Xs, A, _, Ranges, UpdatedRanges) :-
    maxranges_loop(Xs, A, X, Ranges, UpdatedRanges).
maxranges_case(1, X, Xs, A, B, Ranges, UpdatedRanges) :-
    maxranges_loop(Xs, X, X, Ranges, NewRanges),
    update(NewRanges, A, B, UpdatedRanges).

update([], A, B0, [A-B]) :- B is B0+1.
update([A0-B0|Ranges], A, B, UpdatedRanges) :-
    B1 is B+1,
    Sign is sign((B1-A)-(B0-A0)),
    update_case(Sign, [A0-B0|Ranges], A, B1, UpdatedRanges).

update_case( 0, Ranges, A, B, [A-B|Ranges]).
update_case(+1,      _, A, B, [A-B]).
update_case(-1, Ranges, _, _, Ranges).
```

Examples:

```
?- maxrange(X, Y, [1,3,2,7,4,5,6,9,8]).
X = 1,
Y = 10.

?- maxrange(1, 10, [1,3,2,7,4,5,6,9,8]).
true.

?- maxrange(1, 8, [1,3,2,7,4,5,6,9,8]).
false.

?-  maxrange(A, B, [1,2, 4,5,6,7, 9,10,11, 14,15,16,17]).
A = 4,
B = 8 ;
A = 14,
B = 18.

?-  maxranges([1,2, 4,5,6,7, 9,10,11, 14,15,16,17], R).
R = [4-8, 14-18].
```

**EXPLANATION**

- The predicate `update_case/5` updates a list of maximum ranges, with respect to a new range [*A*..*B*), written in Prolog as `A-B`. If its first argument is `0`, then the new range [*A*..*B*) is added to that list; if its first argument is `+1`, that list changes to a new list containing only the range [*A*..*B*); and, its first argument is `-1`, then that list is kept unchanged.

```
?- update_case(0, [14-18], 5, 9, R).
R = [5-9, 14-18].

?- update_case(+1, [14-18], 1, 9, R).
R = [1-9].

?- update_case(-1, [14-18], 3, 7, R).
R = [14-18].
```

- The predicate `update/4` updates a list of maximum ranges with respect to a new range [*A*..*B*]. First, it transforms the closed range [*A*..*B*] into a corresponding right-open range [*A*..*B*+1). Then, if that list is empty, the predicate adds the new range to it. Otherwise, the predicate compares the range [*A*..*B*+1) with the first range in that list, say [*A0*..*B0*). The comparison is made by the expression `Sign is sign((B+1-A)-(B0-A0)`. If both ranges are equal, then `Sign` is `0`; if the first range is bigger than the second, then `Sign` is `+1`; and, if the first range is lesser than the second, then Sign is `-1`. The result of the comparision is used to call the predicate `update_case/5`.

```
?- update([], 17, 19, R).
R = [17-20].

?- update([17-20], 11, 13, R).        % equal
R = [11-14, 17-20].

?- update([11-14, 17-20], 5, 9, R).   % bigger
R = [5-10].

?- update([5-10], 2, 3, R).           % lesser
R = [5-10].
```

- The predicate `maxranges_loop/5` traverses a sorted list (without duplicates) and finds all ranges that are part of it. For each range found, the list of current maximum ranges is updated with a call to the predicate `update/4`.
- The predicate `maxranges/2` is just a wrapper to the predicate `maxranges_loop/5`, that ensures the list is sorted and does not contain duplicates.
- The predicate `maxrange/3` call `maxranges/2` to get the list of maximum ranges and checks whether the range [*A*..*B*) belongs to it.

Comment: Could you explain what each function does (max ranges, maxranges_loop, maxranges_case, update, update_case)? To understand the language more.

Comment: Please, see explanation in my answer.

Comment: In case I want all the ranges that exist in the list (not just the maximum), can I recycle the predicate maxranges_loop?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a simple min & max of the list:

```
list_min_max([H|T], Min, Max) :-
    list_min_max_(T, H, H, Min, Max).
    
list_min_max_([], Min, Max, Min, Max).
list_min_max_([H|T], Min0, Max0, Min, Max) :-
    min(H, Min0, Min1),
    max(H, Max0, Max1),
    list_min_max_(T, Min1, Max1, Min, Max).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- list_min_max([4,9,2,6], Min, Max).
Min = 2,
Max = 9.
```

Comment: It should show False in that case, because the list should contain all the numbers in [2-9) that is 2,3,4,5,6,7,8

Comment: Then please edit the question so it specifies your actual requirements. Some examples would also help to clarify.